# Dropdown doesn't load on selected item

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I cannot load the edit user page with the dropdown on the option that is selected on the model. It is saved correctly in the db when I add a user.

I tried binding it in the edit view but for some reason it is not working.

User.cs (the model)

public string ActivityLevel { get; set; }

Controller

```
    List<SelectListItem> activity = new List<SelectListItem>
    {
        new SelectListItem{ Selected = false ,Text = "Sedentary (little or no exercise)", Value = "Sedentary (little or no exercise)" },
        new SelectListItem{ Selected = false ,Text = "Lightly active (light exercise/sports 1-3 days/week)", Value = "Lightly active (light exercise/sports 1-3 days/week)"  },
        new SelectListItem{ Selected = false ,Text = "Moderately active (moderate exercise/sports 3-5 days/week)", Value = "Moderately active (moderate exercise/sports 3-5 days/week)"  },
        new SelectListItem{ Selected = false ,Text = "Very active (hard exercise/sports 6-7 days a week)", Value = "Very active (hard exercise/sports 6-7 days a week)"  },
        new SelectListItem{ Selected = false ,Text = "Extra active (very hard exercise/sports & a physical job)", Value = "Extra active (very hard exercise/sports & a physical job)"  },
    };
```

public ActionResult NewUser()
        {

```
        User u = new User();
        ViewBag.User = u;
        ViewBag.activity = activity;
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult NewUser(User user)
    {
        try
        {
            db.Users.Add(user);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("AllUsers");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return View();
        }
    }



    public ActionResult EditUser(int id)
    {
        User user = db.Users.Find(id);
        ViewBag.User = user;


        activity.Single(i => i.Value == user.ActivityLevel).Selected = true;
        ViewBag.activity = activity;

        return View();
    }
    [HttpPut]
    public ActionResult EditUser(int id, User requestUser)
    {
        try
        {
            User user = db.Users.Find(id);
            if (TryUpdateModel(user))
            {
                user.Firstname = requestUser.Firstname;
                user.Lastname = requestUser.Lastname;
                user.Height = requestUser.Height;
                user.Weight = requestUser.Weight;
                user.Gender = requestUser.Gender;
                user.Age = requestUser.Age;
                user.Calories = requestUser.Calories;
                user.Bmr = requestUser.Bmr;
                user.ActivityLevel = requestUser.ActivityLevel;
                user.WeightChoice = requestUser.WeightChoice;
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            return RedirectToAction("AllUsers");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Edituser (View): (I think this is the problem, or the get controller of the edit method)

```
<label>Select Activity level</label>

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ActivityLevel,
new SelectList(ViewBag.activity, "Value", "Text"),
new { @class = "form-control" })
```

New User(view):

```
<label>Select Activity level</label>

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ActivityLevel,
new SelectList(ViewBag.activity, "Value", "Text"),
new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: Getting any error?

Comment: no, it just loads the first option always when i try to edit a user.

Comment: Ok, when you edit the data have you set `dropdown` value?

Comment: Please try with add **SelectedValue**  in Edituser view   
`@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ActivityLevel,
new SelectList(ViewBag.activity, "Value", "Text", SelectedValue),
new { @class = "form-control" })`

Comment: @jishansiddique yes it is in the view: Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ActivityLevel,
new SelectList(ViewBag.activity, "Value", "Text"),
new { class = "form-control" }) and also in the get controller, i do:    activity.Single(i => i.Value == user.ActivityLevel).Selected = true;
        ViewBag.activity = activity;

Comment: @HardikMasalawala i dont get it, can u pls write it for me?

Comment: @AlexStaniea `activity.Single` it's is `Viewbag` key?

Comment: @AlexStaniea, Please add **ViewBag.activity** in Edituser view UI as per my code if **ViewBag.activity** is selected value  then do like this 
 `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ActivityLevel, new SelectList(ViewBag.activity, "Value", "Text", ViewBag.activity), new { @class = "form-control" })`

Comment: @HardikMasalawala it doesnt work :(

Comment: @jishansiddique no, it is a function that returns the index of the dropdown that has the value that i want to select, for some reason it doesnt work

Comment: @AlexStaniea,
If possible we can check example any other controller you need to just create one view and set drop-down value with default selection value.

Comment: @AlexStaniea,Please separate your code, 
Pass your selected value in different Viewbag for example **Viewbag.SelectedID** & pass whatever you passing in `ViewBag.activity` EditUser and use like this in Edituser UI `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ActivityLevel, new SelectList(ViewBag.activity, "Value", "Text", Viewbag.SelectedID), new { @class = "form-control" })`

Comment: @AlexStaniea, Please accept my answer as per Stackoverflow policy https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check below solution : 
Please separate your code, Pass your selected value in different Viewbag for example `Viewbag.SelectedID` and 
pass whatever you passing in `ViewBag.activity` EditUser and 
use like this in Edituser UI

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ActivityLevel, new SelectList(ViewBag.activity, "Value", "Text", Viewbag.SelectedID), new { @class = "form-control" })
```